# Android Studio : 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' can't be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm adding a new **database** using **realm** and when I added

**`Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`**

I got an error

> 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' cannot
>   be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

Comment: Can u check the Example 4 [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=io.realm.RealmConfiguration)

Comment: The error message is clear. You need a `RealmConfiguration`. Read the documention to learn how to create one.